# Comparing Strings in while loop

Tags: java, string-comparison

I am trying to write a code that compares the users string to the string 'm' or 'f' and repeating the loop if the users answer doesn't match either letter

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String om = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I will calculate the number of chocolate bar you should eat to maintain your weigth\n"
            + "Please enter letter 'M' if you are a Male\n"
            + "'F' if you are a Female");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, om.equalsIgnoreCase("m"));
// if i don't do this, it says the variables have not been initialized
    boolean m = true;
    boolean f = true;
    if (om == "m"){
     m = om.equalsIgnoreCase("m");
    } else if ( om == "f"){
     f = om.equalsIgnoreCase("f");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The m is: " + m);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The f is: " + f);
//if the user enters one variable the other variable becomes false, thus 
 // activating the while loop
    while (m == false || f == false){
        om = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter letter 'M' if you are a Male\n"
                + "'F' if you are a female");


    }
  /* i tried using '!=' to compare the string that doesn't work, i tired converting the strings to number to make it easier something like the code below:

int g = 2;
if (om = "m"){
g = 0
}
while (g != 0){

}
```

that doesn't work either

So i tried using boolean which worked but if the user doesn't enter one letter the other letter becomes false and activates the while loop

Comment: Strings aren't compared using `==`, but `.equals`, similar to what you did with `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: i used "variable".equals(om); in the while loop but it didn't solve the problem, anything input kept running the loop

Comment: The code is confusing also.  your initial check is not case insensative, but you are setting the variable m or f equal to the check for case insensative.  

So you prompt the user to enter 'M' or 'F' uppercase, then your if does an ==.  your if should be if (om.equalsIgnoreCase("m").

you could also have possible simplification by removing the if and else and just do
m = om.equalsIgnoreCase("m");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to changing the operators from `==` to `.equals()`, you also need to decide if setting them both to `true` before you test for validation is necessary. I would set them to false so you don't need to change the values of the `boolean m` and the `boolean f` in the validation statements.

```
    boolean m = true;
    boolean f = true;

    if (om == "m"){
     m = om.equalsIgnoreCase("m");
    } else if (om == "f"){
     f = om.equalsIgnoreCase("f");
    }
```

could be

```
    boolean m = false;
    boolean f = false;

    if (om.equalsIgnoreCase("m")){
     m = true; //do not need to address the f because its already false.
    } else if (om.equalsIgnoreCase("f")){
     f = true;
    }
```

It's quicker and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed, I guess my first mistake was making the boolean true

Answer (score 1):

You should compare strings with

```
string1.equals(string2)
```

not with

```
string1 == string2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following for strings:

```
if (om.equalsIgnoreCase("m") {
    ....
}
```

When you use `==`, you are comparing the *reference* which the values are pointing to whereas `.equals()` is comparing the actual *value*.

For example:

```
String a = "foo";
String b = "foo";

a == b  // This will return false because it's comparing the reference
a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)  // This however will return true because it's comparing the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `==` for comparing strings, use equals.

Also the test

```
m == false || f == false
```

is not what you want, it always evaluates to true:

- if you enter 'M' then `(f == false)` evaluates to true.
- if you enter 'F' then `(m == false)` evaluates to true.
- if you enter 'X' then `(m == false)` is true and `(f == false)` is true.

Logical OR means that A OR B is true if either A is true, or if B is true.

It should be `(!m && !f)` which means "your input is not 'M' and your input is not 'F'".

Or equivalently, write it as `!(m || f)`: "it is not the case that the input is either 'M' or 'F'".

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your boolean variables as False.

boolean m = false;
 boolean f = false;

This should give you the desired results.

Comment: They're doing a check already in the `if (om == "m")` section and setting booleans. The issue is the string comparison using `==`.